# Dell Precision Tower 7810 goes to sleep on boot Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia

I was running Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my Dell Precision Tower 7810 at work. After updating to 18.04.2, upon restarting, my system reaches the login page and then goes to sleep. I was able to log in remotely through ssh but nothing I tried would wake the system up. After backing up my data, i am currently reinstalling the 18.04.1 again. My kernel was at v15 after the update and I also tried updating to v16, v18

Any advice on what I should try to get my system working??

EDIT 1:

I reinstalled 18.04 using the nomodeset option. This allowed me to boot with no video graphics. But on installing the reccommeded nvidia-390 drivers, my reboot again put my system to sleep. I have a K1200 graphics card on the system.

EDIT 2:

I realized that I had secure boot turned on. On turning that off and reinstalling, I get a scrambled splash screen even after the first reboot. I'm sure its a graphics driver problem. The sad part is it my system was working without ANY glitches only last week.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a graphics card issue :/ got myself a replacement and everything is now working fine.